# Import does not resolve needed type in asp.net mvc 3 with mef

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mef

I used an example on [extensible asp.net mvc 3](http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=259) to build my plug-able application, but I encountered a problem. In a plug-in I declared and implmemented an interface.

But, in plug-in controller when I want to use this class, the application throws an error and it seems that EntityConfig was not initialized. How can this be fixed?

```
[Export(typeof(IController)), ExportMetadata("controllerName", "Concept")]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class ConceptController : Controller
{
   [Import(typeof(IEntityConfig))]
  private IEntityConfig EntityConfig;

  public ActionResult Index()
  {
     var obs = EntityConfig.EntityName;
      return View("~/Bin/Views/Concept/Index.cshtml",obs );
  } 
}

public interface IEntityConfig
{
    string EntityName { get;}
}

[Export(typeof(IEntityConfig))]
public class TestEntity : IEntityConfig
{
    public string EntityName
    {
       get{return "Test";}       
    }
}
```

Edited :
In other side, when I is use [this](https://github.com/moodmosaic/BonusBits.CodeSamples/downloads) example, there is no problem in resolving EntityConfig, but in the view, when I want to load model as follows :

```
@using Concepts
@model Concepts.Models.TestModel
```

the application throws an error and tells me 'The type or namespace name 'Concepts' could not be found', although when I check container after it was initiated, I can see Concepts in in loaded assemblies.

Would you please help me ?
Thanks.

**Edited** :
I uploaded the samples :

[First one](http://arg-co.com/samplemef/ExtensibleMVC3.zip)

[Second one](http://arg-co.com/samplemef/ExtensibleMvcApplicationDemo-Part1.zip)

**Edited** (2011/22/09):
I tested the above code on other [sample](http://www.fidelitydesign.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/MefMvcAndCastleWindsor.zip) that @Matthew Abbott provided in his blog, and it worked, although this sample has been built against mvc 2.0.

Comment: What is the exact error for the first attempt and on what line in your code is it thrown? How do you create the MEF `CompositionContainer`?

Comment: Thanks @WimCoenen to considering my question.For the first sample, I get error in the line containing : "var obs = EntityConfig.EntityName;" and the error is : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", for creating 'CompositionContainer' i uses the same code which is included in the sample. do you want me to upload it ?

Comment: Are you using Part1 or Part2. The Example-Part2 uses the CompositeControllerFactory class. You can view it's unit-tests to see some of it's possible uses here: https://github.com/moodmosaic/System.Web.Mvc.Composition/blob/master/Src/System.Web.Mvc.CompositionUnitTest/CompositeControllerFactoryFacts.cs

Comment: I download both of them, and run both of them. I have made some changes to 'Concept' plug-in which you can download from [here](http://arg-co.com/samplemef/ExtensibleMvcApplicationDemo-Part1.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Looking over your code, can you be sure that the part is actually being imported? Your constructor code for your composition container is such like:

```
var discoverableControllerFactory = new DiscoverableControllerFactory(
    new CompositionContainer(
        new DirectoryCatalog(extensionsPath))
        );
```

You're only including your extensions path as a catalog. Can you guaruntee that you're also including your base application path, e.g.:

```
var discoverableControllerFactory = new DiscoverableControllerFactory(
    new CompositionContainer(
        new AggregateCatalog(
        new DirectoryCatalog("bin"),
        new DirectoryCatalog(extensionsPath)))
        );
```

If the parts actually exist in your Unity container, you could add an export provider that grabs those parts from that container and allows them to be composed by MEF.

As for your second problem, you will need to subclass the `System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider` to ensure it includes assemblies in your extensions directory:

```
namespace ExtensibleMvcApplication
{
    public class CustomRazorBuildProvider : RazorBuildProvider
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Assembly> _assemblies;

        static CustomRazorBuildProvider()
        {
            string extensionsPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Extensions");

            _assemblies = Directory.GetFiles(extensionsPath, "*.dll")
                .Select(Assembly.Load);
        }

        public override void GenerateCode(System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder)
        {
            foreach (var assembly in _assemblies)
                assemblyBuilder.AddAssemblyReference(assembly);

            base.GenerateCode(assemblyBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

Which you'd need to register in your config:

```
<buildProviders>
    <remove extension=".cshtml" />
    <add extension=".cshtml" type="ExtensibleMvcApplication.CustomRazorBuildProvider, ExtensibleMvcApplication"/>
</buildProviders>
```

Comment: Actually in the first sample, which is the one you have developed, I have no problem using strongly-typed views, and the only problem is 'EntityConfig', which cant be initiated. And for the second sample,  I applied 'CustomRazorBuildProvider' and changed config file and changed 'CompositionContainer' , but the application throws this : "Could not load file or assembly "..Concepts.dll' or one of its dependencies". Regards.

Comment: If I put this in my code, my error changes from "are you missing an assembly reference?" to "The view found at '~/Areas/TestPortal/Views/Demo/Index.cshtml' was not created"